# many-to-many relationship springboot mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, api, many-to-many

i have 2 models User and roles , its a many to many relation ship.
i need to add a user and give him a specific role already present in my data base.
------User------

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="user_Id")
    private int userId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name="isActive")
    private boolean isActive;
    @Column(name="lastActive")
    private String lastActive;
    @Column(name="createdDate")
    private String createdDate;
    @Column(name="isBlocked")
    private boolean isBlocked;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "institution_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"user"})
    private Institution institution;
    
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_role",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id",
                            nullable = false, updatable = true)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id",
                            nullable = false, updatable = true)})
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"users"})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

}
```

--------Roles--------

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="role_Id")
    private int roleId;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"roles"})
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

}
```

and the application's controller

```
@PostMapping("/addUser")
    public String addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userrepository.save(user);
        return "user saved with name: " + user.getName();
    }
```

and this is the json body i send with the api request.

```
{
        "userId" : 7,
        "name": "test",
        "lastname": "testlast",
        "email": "testtest@yahoo.com",
        "password": "test123",
        "lastActive": "04/05/21",
        "createdDate": "02/04/20",
        "institution": {
            "institutionId": 4
            },
       "roles": [
            {
                "roleId": 2
            }
        ],  
        "active": false,
        "blocked": true
    }
```

everything worls just fine to my user-has-role table a record is added with the userId = 7 and roleId=2
but the problem is that the table role is getting updated and the fields name and description are getting erased and replaced by null values...
any ideas please

Comment: You need an intermediary table.

Comment: i do have it ... its user_has_role check the entities

Comment: I think you need to use the `Put` method for this `@PutMapping`

Comment: i will try it now

Comment: it didn't work it also deleted the record from the role table...
thats the only problem 
its like updating the role table and setting name and description to null because in the json body they are not specified...

Comment: @SSK PutMapping didn't fix my error i kinda explained more in the comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added `CascadeType.PERSIST` to `User` and `Role` `@ManyToMany` join.
When the `User` entity is persisted to the EntityManager, it will also persist the `Role` entity. As you are passing the primary key in the request payload for `Role` it will create/update the Role table.

You need to remove the `CascadeType.PERSIST` from joining and it will work as expected.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "user_has_role",
            joinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id",
                            nullable = false, updatable = true)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "role_id",
                            nullable = false, updatable = true)})
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"users"})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: i just tried it and sadly it still the same problem updating the roles table and setting name and description to null..
any ideas?

Comment: Try removing cascade itself

Comment: yes i just did now
i removed all the cascade values and it actually worked !!
thank you so much always saving me !